# Serializing and deserializing multiple objects in Java

Tags: java, serialization

**Below is the steps how my application need to work.**

Once I start my application:

1. It needs to keep on accepting input from the user that is in the form of a string.
2. Once I get any input I need to serialize it.
3. After that, I need to Deserialize all the objects stored in the file so that I will not loose my previous serialized objects stored in the file.

How can it be implemented? Each Time I am able to deserialize only one object that came at last. Below is the code which I am using for single input. I can't convert all the input into single object because my application needs to keep on running for the whole day and it has to accept input at any time.

**code for serializing**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dummyserial implements Serializable {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    String input;   
    public void work()

    {       System.out.println("give an input");
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
            input=user_input.next( );

    }
    public static char sa='n';
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("pree Y to continue or N to exit");
        Scanner flag= new Scanner(System.in);
        sa=flag.next().charAt(0);

if (sa=='y'){
        Dummyserial obj=new Dummyserial();
        try{
                     FileOutputStream fileOut =new FileOutputStream("C:/Workouts/DummyStrng.ser");
                     ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
                     obj.work();
                     out.writeObject(obj);
                     out.close();
                     fileOut.close();
                     System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in C:/Workouts/Strng.ser");
            }
            catch(IOException i)
              {
                  i.printStackTrace();
              }
        }}
    }
```

**code for deserializing**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DummyDeserial {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Dummyserial obj=null;
         try
          {
             FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:/Workouts/DummyStrng.ser");
             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
             obj = (Dummyserial) in.readObject();
             in.close();
             fileIn.close();
          }catch(IOException i)
          {
             i.printStackTrace();
             return;
          }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
          {
             System.out.println("Employee class not found");
             c.printStackTrace();
             return;
          }


        System.out.printf("%s",obj.input);
        System.out.println();

        }

    }
```

Comment: so you need to append to the file then.  You are overwriting it.  Alternatively, save the objects in a list and write to file all at once.

Comment: @Scary but i want to process my input one by one.i dont want my input to be stored in list all at once.is it not possible to manage without overwriting the previous objects.

Comment: Just keep the `FileOutputStream` and the `ObjectOutputStream` open for the life of the program, instead of creating new ones per object to be serialized. @ScaryWombat You can't just append to a file of serialized objects without taking special measures.